# Nest multiple async await

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

I have the following Express endpoint:

```
const all = require('promise-all');

router.post('/verify', upload.single('photo'), async (req, res) => {
  ...    
  await all({'p1': p1, 'p2': p2}).then((response) => {
      ...
      console.log("Response:", 
      ruleCtrl.manageRule(detection, res);
  });
});
```

`ruleCtrl.manageRule`is as follows:

```
export async function manageRule(identifierDetected, res) {
  let rule = db.getRule(identifierDetected);
  await all([rule]).then((ruleExtracted) => {
    ...
    res.json(ruleExtracted);
  }).catch((err) => {
    res.status(418).send("DOCUMENT_NOT_RECOGNIZED");
  });
}
```

and `db.getRule`:

```
export async function getRule(idRule) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Rule.findOne({ruleID: idRule}, (err, rule) => {
        if (err) {
            reject("MongoDB Rule error: " + err);
        } else {
            resolve(rule);
        }
    });
  })
}
```

My response is into `manageRule` and this function depends of the values extracted into the `await all`. So, right now, Express is returning a response before get the information from mongoose database (`db`).

Which is the way to handle this issue?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Is "db.getRule(identifierDetected);" async?

Comment: There's little point to `await all.then()`.  Just leave off the `await` if you're going to use `.then()`.  Or, do `let results = await all(...)` without the `.then()` and then use `results` on the next line of code.  Pick one style or the other.  You are using `await`, but not taking advantage of why you use `await`.  That makes no sense.  Either use it with its advantages or don't use it.

Comment: @Faheem updated my post.

Comment: There's also no point to using `Promise.all()` with a single promise.

Comment: @jfriend00 I've removed last await (agree with you. It does not have sense), but same result...

Comment: @jfriend00 this snippet is a simplified version of my code. Next release that step will have multiple promises to wait :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would refactor your code a bit to make it easier to read, and also return the result from `ruleCtrl.manageRule(detection, res);`.
The request might simply be timing out since your original code is missing a return there or an await (to make sure it finishes executing)

Express endpoint:

```
const all = require('promise-all');

router.post('/verify', upload.single('photo'), async (req, res) => {
  ...
  // Catch any exceptions from the promises. This is the same as using .catch
  try {
    // Lets assign the returned responses to variable
    let [p1Result, p2Result] = await all({'p1': p1, 'p2': p2});
    ...
    console.log("Responses:", p1Result, p2Result);
    // return the response from manageRule method
    return ruleCtrl.manageRule(detection, res);
  } catch(err) {
    // Handle err here
  }
});
```

One of the great benefits with async await is moving away from chained promises, so simply return the result from the await to a variable instead of using `.then()`

ruleCtrl.manageRule

```
export async function manageRule(identifierDetected, res) {
  // Use try catch here to catch error from db.getRule. Assign to variable and return 
  // res.json  
  try {      
    let ruleExtracted = await db.getRule(identifierDetected);
    ...
    return res.json(ruleExtracted);
  } catch(err) {
    return res.status(418).send("DOCUMENT_NOT_RECOGNIZED");
  }
}
```

You dont have to return `res.json` or `res.status` here, I just like to keep track of when I want to end function execution.

You could refactor the `ruleCtrl.manageRule` method even further by not sending in res as a parameter but by returning the result from `db.getRule` instead. Let `router.post('/verify`) handle req and res, so to make it even easier to read.